# Visual Studio publish app.config file

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, app-config, publish

I want to publish my WPF application to create installator.
But I'm using App.config to store 2 app options eg: resolution.

User can change this parameter inside app and I want it to be saved.
Changing works fine until next opening app.
Parameters are set to default.

Is it publish problem? Or maybe I've done something wrong in code ?

Changing App.config parameter in code:

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Set("Resolution", Res);
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Set("Sound", Sound);
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        config.AppSettings.Settings.Remove("Resolution");
        config.AppSettings.Settings.Remove("Sound");
        config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("Resolution", Res);
        config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("Sound", Sound);
        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Minimal);
        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Set("Resolution", Res);
        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Set("Sound", Sound);
```

This works.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("Resolution", Res);
    config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("Sound", Sound);
    config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Minimal);
```

Comment: With this code, my app doesn't want to start after changing options.

Comment: And since then I'm getting error:
error while trying to run project could not load file or assembly